# Xamarin.Forms MasterDetail page NavBar customization

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, navigation, prism, master-detail

I'm in need of a large dose of help for an issue with the `MasterDetail` page in **Xamarin.Forms**.

What I'm trying to do is, very simply, to customize the `NavigationBar`'s background to use a gradient. My setup is a **Xamarin.Forms** app with **Prism**, where I first login the user and then navigate to a `MasterDetail` page like so:

```
await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("MyMasterDetailPage/NavigationPage/MyDetailPage")
```

The problem I am running into is that no matter what I do I can't change the color of the `NavigationBar`.

I've tried several different variants of `CustomRenderers` (for **Android** currently), as well as just adding a custom `TitleView` to the `Detail` page in the **PCL** project. I've also tried changing the *styles.xml* file, changing the *ToolBar.axml* to use the drawable I've made, but I've still got no luck so far.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've been struggling for a few days now with this issue.

Below is a screenshot of what's going on:

[image]

Toolbar.axml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
android:background="@drawable/gradient_background_drawable"
 />
```

styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>

  <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
  </style>
  <!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
  <style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!--If you are using revision 22.1 please use just windowNoTitle. Without android:-->
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <!-- Set theme colors from http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette -->
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#89D362</item>
    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#89D362</item>
    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
         which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
    <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
         colorControlHighlight and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
    <!--<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>-->

    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
  </style>

  <style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">#89D362</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

gradient_background_drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <gradient android:type="linear"
            android:angle="270"
            android:startColor="#000E0E"
            android:endColor="#3D3939">
  </gradient>

</shape>
```

MasterDetailPageRenderer:

```
protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
        {
            base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
            var toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
            if (toolbar != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < toolbar.ChildCount; i++)
                {
                    var child = toolbar.GetChildAt(i);
                    child.Background = Context.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.gradient_background_drawable);
                }

                toolbar.Background = Context.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.gradient_background_drawable);
            }
        }
```

NavigationPageRenderer:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<NavigationPage> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (e.OldElement != null || Element == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var actionBar = ((FormsAppCompatActivity)Context).SupportActionBar;
            actionBar.SetBackgroundDrawable(Context.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.gradient_background_drawable));
        }

        protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
        {
            base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
            var toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
            if (toolbar != null)
            {
                //for (int i = 0; i < toolbar.ChildCount; i++)
                //{
                //    var child = toolbar.GetChildAt(i);
                //    child.Background = Context.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.gradient_background_drawable);
                //}

                toolbar.Background = Context.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.gradient_background_drawable);
            }
        }

        public override void OnViewAdded(Android.Views.View child)
        {
            base.OnViewAdded(child);
            if (child.GetType() == typeof(Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar))
            {
                _toolbar = (Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar)child;

                _toolbar.Background = Context.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.gradient_background_drawable);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved the function by creating a new app with template `Master-Detail Page`.
The method is to set the `background` of `Toolbar.axml` just as you mentioned.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" 
android:background="@drawable/gradient_background_drawable"
/>
```

To make the effect more obvious,I change the gradient color. You can change back to your own gradient color.

file `gradient_background_drawable.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <gradient android:type="linear"
            android:angle="270"
            android:startColor="#008B00"
            android:endColor="#9AFF9A">
  </gradient>
</shape>
```

Besides,remember to remove the Property relatived with `Background` about toolbar in file `App.xaml` .

file `App.xaml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="FormApp202011.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <!--Global Styles  -->
            <Color x:Key="NavigationPrimary">#2196F3</Color>
            <Style TargetType="NavigationPage">
                <Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="Red" />

            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! It was the bit about the App.xaml - I completely ignored it and didn't check for global styles there... didn't even think to do so since I didn't expect there to be preset style for the BarBackgroundColor.